# Why dictionary property setter does not execute while adding a new item in dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a class `Wrapper` which has a dictionary property `DictA` and I want to serialize the instance of class as soon as a new item added into dictionary. However when I insert a new item in `DictA`, the `DictA` property setter does not execute. I think, I am missing some fundamental behavior of dictionaries and I need help to understand it. Below is the example code, which I am using...

```
public class Product 
{
    public string Name     { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }
    public string[ ] Sizes { get; set; }
}

public class Wrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private Dictionary<string, Product> dictA_;    
    public Wrapper() => dictA_ = new Dictionary<string, Product>();

    public Dictionary<string, Product> DictA 
    {
        get => dictA_;
        set 
        {
            dictA_ = value;
            SerializeToJson();  // trying to serialize in simple fashion without event handling           
        }
    }

    public void SerializeToJson() 
    {
        string path = @"..\JsonTest.json";  // path
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( this );
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer( );

        using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path)) 
        {
            using(JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw)) 
            {
                serializer.Serialize( writer, this );
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    var product    = new Product();
    product.Name   = "Apple";
    product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
    product.Sizes  = new string[] {"Small"};

    var temp = new Wrapper();
    temp.DictA.Add("test", product);
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 15);

    temp.DictA.Add("test2", product);
    Thread.Sleep(1000 * 15);

    temp.DictA.Add("test3", product);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: because the dictionary doesnt change, the items in it do.

Comment: A property's setter is called when you assign a new reference to it, and that's not happening at all here. You would need a custom class that overrides the Dictionary's Add method for this.

Comment: Setter of the property will execute when you do `temp.DictA = someotherdictionary;` . Not when you add item to DictA.

Comment: the setter triggers only using assignment operator `=`

Comment: Your wrapper could inherit from `Dictionary<TKey,Tvalue>`. Then you could ensure what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments say, you're adding to a collection, not setting a collections value, a good solution would be to create a custom class and inherit from Dictionary, doing something like this would solve your issue:

```
class SerialisableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public new void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        SerializeToJson();
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, I have to update a specific entry in dictionary. Tvalue is user defined type and has several properties and want to update to one specific property in a specific dictionary entry and then want to do serialization. Do you know how dictionary updates are carried out?

Answer (score 3):

The setter is only for assigning a reference to a dictionary to that property. It is unrelated to adding values to whatever dictionary the property references.

If you want some logic to occur when a new value is added to a dictionary, you should write your own class implementing `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Use the existing `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implementation to back it but do your own logic in your `Add` method implementation before adding the value into the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I managed to find the solution which I was looking. Please review and if there is mistake highlight it:

```
public class Product {

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime Expiry { get; set; }

    public string[ ] Sizes { get; set; }

  }

  public class DictionaryWithJsonSerailization<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, INotifyPropertyChanged {

    #region Events

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion

    #region Private fields


    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _interalDictionary;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public DictionaryWithJsonSerailization( ) {
      _interalDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>( );
    }




    #endregion

    #region implementation of IDictionary<TKey, TValue> interface



    public TValue this[ TKey key ] {
      get {
        try {
          return ( TValue )_interalDictionary[ key ];
        }
        catch( Exception ex ) {
          return default( TValue );
        }
      }

      set {
        _interalDictionary[ key ] = value;
        NotifyObserversOfChange( );
      }
    }

    public ICollection<TKey> Keys {
      get {
        return _interalDictionary.Select( x => ( TKey )x.Key ).ToList( );
      }
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> Values {
      get {
        return _interalDictionary.Select( x => ( TValue )x.Value ).ToList( );
      }
    }

    public int Count {
      get {
        return _interalDictionary.Count;
      }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly {
      get {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public void Add( TKey key, TValue value ) {
      _interalDictionary.Add( key, value );
      NotifyObserversOfChange( );
    }

    public void Add( KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item ) {
      _interalDictionary.Add( item.Key, item.Value );
      NotifyObserversOfChange( );
    }

    public void Clear( ) {
      _interalDictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>( );
      NotifyObserversOfChange( );
    }

    public bool Contains( KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item ) {

      return _interalDictionary.Contains( item );
    }

    public bool ContainsKey( TKey key ) {

      return _interalDictionary.ContainsKey( key );
    }

    public void CopyTo( KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[ ] array, int arrayIndex ) {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    public bool Remove( TKey key ) {
      try {
        _interalDictionary.Remove( key );
        NotifyObserversOfChange( );
        return true;
      }
      catch( Exception ex ) {
        return false;
      }

    }

    public bool Remove( KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item ) {
      try {
        _interalDictionary.Remove( item.Key );
        NotifyObserversOfChange( );
        return true;
      }
      catch( Exception ex ) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue( TKey key, out TValue value ) {
      try {
        value = ( TValue )_interalDictionary[ key ];
        return true;
      }
      catch( Exception ex ) {
        value = default( TValue );
        return false;
      }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator( ) {
      return ( ( IDictionary<TKey, TValue> )this ).GetEnumerator( );
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator( ) {
      return _interalDictionary.GetEnumerator( );
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private methods

    private void NotifyObserversOfChange( ) {
      var propertyHandler = PropertyChanged;
      if( propertyHandler != null ) {
        if( propertyHandler != null ) {
          propertyHandler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Count" ) );
          propertyHandler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Keys" ) );
          propertyHandler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "Values" ) );
          propertyHandler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "this" ) );
        }
      }
    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator( ) {
      throw new NotImplementedException( );
    }

    #endregion


  }

  public class Wrapper {

    DictionaryWithJsonSerailization<string, Product> dictA_;

    public Wrapper( ) {
      dictA_ = new DictionaryWithJsonSerailization<string, Product>( );
      dictA_.PropertyChanged += ( sener, i ) => SerializeToJson( );


    }

    public DictionaryWithJsonSerailization<string, Product> DictA {
      get {
        return dictA_;
      }
      set {
        dictA_ = value;
      }
    }

    public void SerializeToJson( ) {
      string path = @"...\JsonTest.json";
      string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject( this );
      JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer( );

      using( StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( path ) ) {
        using( JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter( sw ) ) {
          serializer.Serialize( writer, this );
        }
      }
    }

  }

static void Main( string[ ] args ) {


    Product product = new Product( );
    product.Name = "Apple";
    product.Expiry = new DateTime( 2008, 12, 28 );
    product.Sizes = new string[ ] { "Small" };

    var temp = new Wrapper( );
    temp.DictA.Add( "test", product );
    Thread.Sleep( 1000 * 15 );
    temp.DictA.Add( "test2", product );
    Thread.Sleep( 1000 * 15 );
    temp.DictA.Add( "test3", product );
  }
```

I am trying to add items after some delay in dictionary and whenever, a new items is added into dictionary, object having that dictionary is stored in json file on computer drive.

Comment: I remember a class called ccurrency manager, maybe You can use this to observe changes in the dict...